# Run an akka class in a certain period of a time

Tags: scala, akka

I'm working with akka.io in Scala. I have a need to run some actor's class so that it would be running "constantly" after a certain period of time, let's say, every 2 minutes.

Is there a special way in akka to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Akka Scheduler interface like so inside your Actor class:

```
//Use the system's dispatcher as ExecutionContext
import system.dispatcher

//Schedules to send the "foo"-message to the someActor after 2 minutes
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(120 seconds, testActor, "foo")
```

You can find the Akka Documentation [Here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0-RC2/scala/scheduler.html).

Comment: Sorry, answered before noticing it was dup.

Comment: it says " not found: object system"